# What is the correct way in node.js Express to show a spinner while performing a time consuming post?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a post which kicks off a large processing task which can take upwards of half a minute.

What is the correct way to send back to the response a spinner and then when the task completes redirect or show the results?

Should I use render() on a temporary view, and then use redirect() asynchronously when the task finishes?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
exports.postForm = function (req, res) {
console.log('postForm');
logger.info('Request Data:' + JSON.stringify(req.body));

// Do big task here... but how to tell user its happening?

};
```

Update - More details on the problem:

So the specific problem I have is this: When I hit submit button, the post comes back to this route in Express. From here I can send content or redirect, whatever I want. Say I redirect to a "Processing" page, then kick off an asynchronous call to start the data collection. How then, when that is done, can I redirect again to the "Processing Complete" page?

I suspect I may need to do all this in Socket.IO and not use html post to submit the form. I guess then I can "on click" use socket.io to submit the data, and then i could in an AJAX like fashion rewrite part of the webpage to indicate "processing" and then when I get the event to say complete via socket.io I could rewrite the page again to say done. Does this seem like the best way forward?

Comment: There are many different ways to do this...not just one and certainly no "correct way" except one that works for you.  What have you tried so far and what errors or problems did you encounter?  This site is really helpful with specific questions, not so much broad ones.

Comment: Updated to provide more specifics.

Comment: This has nothing to do with anything server-side.  And, you can't render something and redirect later... at that point, the headers are already sent.  Make an AJAX request client-side, and show your loading gif until the request completes.

Comment: But how long can I keep the request open for? I mean, it could take a few minutes to generate this data. So, if I understand you correctly, you would not respond to the request server-side until the data generation has completed? I guess I don't see how its not server-side when thats where the processing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you add a callback to the render (or, in modern scripts, `async/await`), you can render as many times as you want.

```js
const asyncBlock = async () =>
{
    await res.render('somePageWithLoadingGif');
    await someTimeConsumingTask();
    res.render('tada');
}
```