# Rendering webpage while waiting for query finish using async/await

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I want to show some processing gif when waiting to query finish, after that render main page with results.

```
board: async (req, res, next) => {

await res.render('waiting.ejs');

      const result = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        db2.query(queryboard.join(';'), (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(`sql error ${queryboard}`);
          }
          resolve(result)
        })
      });

      return res.render('index.ejs')

}
```

I'm a bit new in async/await so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Error:
`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

this is idea what I want to implement:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62413461/8522950

Comment: remove `await res.render('waiting.ejs');`

Comment: @hoangdv `await res.render('waiting.ejs');` is for showing a processing gif like 'waiting until query finish...', thats whole problem and idea

Comment: I think you need to read about server rendering vs client-side rendering. What you need is clientside rendering, what you do is server side rendering.

Comment: Thats what I was think so :)

Comment: @hoangdv to be honest this answer let me think it is possible so I started trying:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62413461/8522950